Random test failures in kafka integration tests with TestContainer
I'm experiencing inconsistent failures in my Kafka integration tests using TestContainers. The tests involve simple produce and consume operations along with database seeding, but sometimes they pass and sometimes they fail when run as part of a test suite. But running them alone succeeds
I'm testing a background service that should consume a message and then produce some messages for various topics. The topics are configured via appsettings, and to ensure unique topics for each test method, I am configuring my Kafka configuration class accordingly. Additionally, I am using two in-memory databases, each created with new names for every test. For each test method, I create a new consumer and producer, with the consumer having a unique GroupId.
I have a one-time setup and teardown for the Kafka container, as well as setup and teardown for consumers, producers, and databases. This includes disposing of the databases, the host, and deleting the topics.
    protected TDataContext _dataContext;

    protected ReferenceDataContext _refContext;

    protected IContainer _kafkaContainer;

    protected IHost _host;

    private Fixture _fixture;

    private int _port;

    private AO2KafkaConfiguration _kafkaConfiguration;

    private IConsumer<Ignore, string> _consumer;

    private IProducer<string, byte[]> _producer;

    private Dictionary<string, string> _consumerTopics;

    private Dictionary<string, string> _producerTopics;

    private List<string> _topics => [.. _consumerTopics.Values, .. _producerTopics.Values];

    protected string _bootstrapServer;

    private IHostBuilder _hostBuilder;

    protected abstract IHostBuilder GetHostBuilder();
    protected abstract Task SetDataInDatabase();


    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public async Task OneTimeSetup()
    {
        _fixture = new Fixture();
        _port = _fixture.Create<int>() % (5000 - 1000 + 1) + 1000;
        _bootstrapServer = GenerateBootstrapServer();

        await StartKafkaContainerAsync();
    }


    [OneTimeTearDown]
    public async Task OneTimeTearDown()
    {
        await _kafkaContainer.DisposeAsync();
    }

    [SetUp]
    public async Task SetUp()
    {
        _hostBuilder = GetHostBuilder();

        ConfigureKafkaConfiguration();

        _consumer = CreateConsumer();
        _producer = CreateProducer();

        InitializeDbsAsync();

        _host = _hostBuilder.Build();

        await CreateTopicsAsync();
    }

    [TearDown]
    public async Task TearDown()
    {
        _consumer.Dispose();
        _producer.Dispose();

        await _dataContext.DisposeAsync();
        await _refContext.DisposeAsync();

        _host.Dispose();

        await DeleteTopicsAsync();
    }

    protected ConsumeResult<Ignore, string> ConsumeTestMessage(string topicName, int timeoutMilliseconds, int retryRounds)
    {
        _consumer.Subscribe(topicName);
        ConsumeResult<Ignore, string> consumeResult = null;
        retryRounds = 5;
        timeoutMilliseconds = 5000;
        var counter = 0;
        while (counter < retryRounds)
        {

            consumeResult = _consumer.Consume(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds));
            if (consumeResult is not null)
            {
                return consumeResult;
            }
            counter++;
            Task.Delay(timeoutMilliseconds);
        }
        return consumeResult;
    }

    
    protected async Task ProduceTestMessageAsync<T>(string publishTopicName, string jsonFixture)
    {
        var message = await ReadMessageAsync<T>(jsonFixture);
        var kafkaMessage = ConstructKafkaMessage(message);
        await _producer.ProduceAsync(publishTopicName, kafkaMessage);
    }

    private static Message<string, byte[]> ConstructKafkaMessage<T>(T message)
    {
        var compositeMessage = new KafkaCompositeMessage(new JsonUtf8Serializer(), (Message<string, byte[]>)null);
        compositeMessage.MessageComponents.Add(typeof(T).Name, message);
        return compositeMessage.ToKafkaMessage();
    }

    private string GenerateBootstrapServer() => $"localhost:{_port}";

    private void ConfigureKafkaConfiguration()
    {
        _hostBuilder.ConfigureServices(delegate (IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var descriptor = services.FirstOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == typeof(AO2KafkaConfiguration))
                ?? throw new Exception("Can't find AO2KafkaConfiguration while initializing kafka test container");

            _kafkaConfiguration = (AO2KafkaConfiguration)descriptor.ImplementationInstance;
            _kafkaConfiguration.BootstrapServers = _bootstrapServer;
            _kafkaConfiguration.ConsumerTopics = ConvertToUniqueTopics(_kafkaConfiguration.ConsumerTopics);
            _kafkaConfiguration.ProducerTopics = ConvertToUniqueTopics(_kafkaConfiguration.ProducerTopics);

            _consumerTopics = _kafkaConfiguration.ConsumerTopics;
            _producerTopics = _kafkaConfiguration.ProducerTopics;

        });
    }

    private Dictionary<string, string> ConvertToUniqueTopics(IDictionary<string, string> dictionary) =>
        dictionary.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => $"{kvp.Value}-{Guid.NewGuid()}");

    private async Task StartKafkaContainerAsync()
    {
        var kafkaContainerName = $"kafka-integration_{_fixture.Create<string>()}";
        _kafkaContainer = new ContainerBuilder()
            .WithImage("bitnami/kafka:3.5.1")
            .WithName(kafkaContainerName)
            .WithHostname(kafkaContainerName)
            .WithEnvironment("KAFKA_CFG_NODE_ID", "0")
            .WithEnvironment("KAFKA_CFG_PROCESS_ROLES", "controller,broker")
            .WithEnvironment("KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS", $"0@{kafkaContainerName}:9093")
            .WithEnvironment("KAFKA_KRAFT_CLUSTER_ID", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstux")
            .WithEnvironment("KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS", $"PLAINTEXT://:9092,CONTROLLER://:9093,EXTERNAL://:{_port}")
            .WithEnvironment("KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS", $"PLAINTEXT://{kafkaContainerName}:9092,EXTERNAL://127.0.0.1:{_port}")
            .WithEnvironment("KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP", "CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT")
            .WithEnvironment("KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES", "CONTROLLER")
            .WithEnvironment("KAFKA_CFG_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME", "PLAINTEXT")
            .WithEnvironment("KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE", "false")
            .WithExposedPort(_port)
            .WithPortBinding(_port,_port)
            .WithWaitStrategy(Wait.ForUnixContainer().UntilPortIsAvailable(_port))
            .Build();

        await _kafkaContainer.StartAsync();
    }

    private IConsumer<Ignore, string> CreateConsumer()
    {
        var consumerConfig = new ConsumerConfig()
        {
            BootstrapServers = _bootstrapServer,
            GroupId = $"GroupId-{Guid.NewGuid()}",
            AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest
        };
        return new ConsumerBuilder<Ignore, string>(consumerConfig).Build();
    }

    private IProducer<string, byte[]> CreateProducer()
    {
        var producerConfig = new ProducerConfig()
        {
            BootstrapServers = _bootstrapServer,
        };
        return new ProducerBuilder<string, byte[]>(producerConfig).Build();
    }

    private async Task CreateTopicsAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            using var adminClient = new AdminClientBuilder(new AdminClientConfig { BootstrapServers = _bootstrapServer, }).Build();
            await adminClient.CreateTopicsAsync(_topics.Select(topic => new TopicSpecification() { Name = topic, NumPartitions = 1, ReplicationFactor = 1 }));
        }
        catch (CreateTopicsException e)
        {
            // Ignored
        }
    }

    private void InitializeDbsAsync()
    {
        var dbName = $"InMemoryDb_{_fixture.Create<string>()}";
        _hostBuilder.ConfigureServices(delegate (IServiceCollection services)
        {
            _refContext = CreateInMemoryReferenceDataContext(dbName);
            InitInMemoryAppDataContext<TDataContext>(services, dbName);
            var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            _dataContext = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<TDataContext>();
        });
    }

    private static ReferenceDataContext CreateInMemoryReferenceDataContext(string dbName)
    {
        var dbContextOptionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ReferenceDataContext>();
        dbContextOptionsBuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase(dbName);
        dbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
        dbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableDetailedErrors();
        dbContextOptionsBuilder.ConfigureWarnings(a =>
        {
            a.Ignore(InMemoryEventId.TransactionIgnoredWarning);
        });
        return new ReferenceDataContext(dbContextOptionsBuilder.Options);
    }

    private static void InitInMemoryAppDataContext<TContext>(IServiceCollection services, string dbName) where TContext : DbContext
    {
        var item = services.SingleOrDefault((d) => d.ServiceType == typeof(DbContextOptions<TContext>));
        services.Remove(item);
        services.AddDbContext<TContext>(delegate (DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        {
            options.UseInMemoryDatabase(dbName);
            options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
            options.EnableDetailedErrors();
            options.ConfigureWarnings(a =>
            {
                a.Ignore(InMemoryEventId.TransactionIgnoredWarning);
            });
        });
    }

    private async Task DeleteTopicsAsync()
    {
        using var adminClient = new AdminClientBuilder(new AdminClientConfig { BootstrapServers = _bootstrapServer, }).Build();
        var topicsToDelete = adminClient
            .GetMetadata(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1))
            .Topics
            .Select(x => x.Topic);

        await adminClient.DeleteTopicsAsync(topicsToDelete);
    }

// Example of test shortened

 var someTopic = kafkaConfiguration.ProducerTopics[nameof(SomeClass)];
 var someOtherTopic = kafkaConfiguration.ConsumerTopics[nameof(SomeClass2)];

 // Act
 _ = Task.Run(async () => await _host.RunAsync());
 await ProduceTestMessageAsync<Class>(someTopic, data);

 // Assert
 var message = ConsumeTestMessage(someOtherTopic, 5000, 10)?.Message?.Value;



Tried to re-create the Kafka container for each test, but some tests are still failing
